# SAS : import Excel file (xlsx) with colum containing different date formats

Tags: excel, sas

I have a problem with importing my data in SAS.

I have one column containing different date formats:

```
01/01/2018 19:00:45
01/02/2018 18:00:36
01/MAY/2019 06:05:55 PM
...
```

SAS doesn't import all :

```
.
.
01MAY2019
```

even thought I use this code :

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= work.DONN2 
            DATAFILE= "&path_input\TOTO.xlsx" 
            DBMS=EXCEL ;
            SHEET='data';
            GETNAMES=YES;
            MIXED=YES;
            SCANTEXT=YES;
            USEDATE=NO;
            SCANTIME=NO;
RUN;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Excel, is the third cell a date value with a custom format, or a cell formatted as text ?

Comment: Are you importing from excel or from a text file ?

Comment: Richard, the column has 2 formats : personalized and standard.

Comment: Dirk Horsten, I am importing excel file (xlsx)

Comment: Your best bet, unfortunately is to convert the file to CSV, read it in as character and then convert it in SAS using a few IF/THEN statements. Or you can try DBSASTYPE with PCFILES engine but I suspect that's not worth the effort. Is this a one time thing or will you need to turn this into a reproducible, repeatable process.

Comment: Are the cells in that column in the Excel file all DATE values with different display formats? Or does the column contain a mix of actual DATE values and strings?  You might have better luck just use DBMS=XLSX instead of DBMS=EXCEL.

Comment: I am not sure there is a standard date format that shows military time with seconds.  Are the first two custom formatted `m/d/yy h:mm:ss;@` and `d/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` -- Not sure what custom format code would cause uppercase `MAY` though

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is an option to choose formats while using PROC IMPORT for Excel files. My solution is a workaround to that.

If you can open the Excel sheet and export as CSV then using two DATA Steps you can have what you want.
As an example, I have assumed that there is a file in csv format and it has the following data somewhere on your computer.

```
Date, NumberOfPatients, Survived
01/01/2018 19:00:45,23,22
01/02/2018 18:00:36,55,55
01/MAY/2019 06:05:55 PM,34,32
01/JUN/2019 06:05:55 PM,32,29
```

So you may want to read the CSV file that you converted above. In the first pass it will not read in correct format. The only trick here is to set the length of Date column to 23 characters. After that you have created a temporary data called Temp and then do a second pass of DATA step as below, to get the dataset called Want. Please note two conversions: first a generic ANYDTDTM followed by DATEAMPM conversion. Doing all these tricks as below, should give you what you want.

```
DATA Temp;
    LENGTH Date $23;
    INFILE "NameAndPathOfTheFile.csv" DLM="," FIRSTOBS=2;
    INPUT Date NumberOfPatients Survived;
RUN;

DATA Want;
    SET Temp;
    NewDate = INPUT(Date,ANYDTDTM23.);
    FORMAT NewDate DATEAMPM23.;
    DROP Date;
    RENAME NewDate=Date;
RUN;
```

Now the data should be in correct form and you can do all operations allowed on datetime type of variables.
If you do PROC PRINT of the Want dataset you created above, you should see something as below.

[The Date column is in correct format in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GYbq.png)